# Python Pandas return an array instead of series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
for j in account_list:
 my_dict['name'] = (df[df['DESC'].str.contains(j)]['Hostname'].iloc[0])
```

This one works fine and returns an array of names, but if I changed it to:

```
 for j in account_list:
      my_dict['name'] = (df[df['DESC'].str.startswith('Account')]['Hostname'])
```

It returns a series not an array, I have tried asarray() and as_matrix, none of them returns an array like the first one, could you please help me?

Sample from the excel sheet:
https://paste.pound-python.org/show/VfRmfJEWavU14luvFXQs/

EDIT: Expected result should be like this:

```
wordpress
wordpress
drupal
magento
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a numpy array as elements of `my_dict`, you should be able to cast it like this:

```
np.array(df[df['DESC'].str.startswith('Account')]['Hostname'])
```

Or if you mean a Python list, just use `list` in place of `np.array`.

Comment: Thank you, list was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow. Your code doesn't really return anything, but I take it that the `my_dict` contains Series whilst you would like it to contain an array? Try `the_pandas_serie_object.values()`.

Comment: Yes that's right for the first assumption, with the first line my dict includes an array, for the second one it returns series and can't get it to return an array like the first one.

Comment: I tried .values and unfortunately it returned all the names in one big chunk unlike the first line in my initial code which was returning one at the time, so it returned ['wordpress,wordpress,drupal,magento'] unlike the first line with the iloc it was returning line1 wordpress line2 wordpress line 3 drupal line 4 magento